# Realm & Swift: don't update a column after first load

Tags: json, swift, realm

For my current project I'm working with Realm. I make 2 calls to the backend, to get my JSON data. The first call fills my database up (named Categories) with a category `Id, Name & a imageUrl`.

```
class Categories: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    dynamic var name:String?
    dynamic var imageUrl:String?

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }


    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        imageUrl <- map["imageUrl"]
    }    
}
```

The second call gets back a lot of different information + for each item there is also a category `Name & Id` available, which I also write to the "Categories" Object (note: there is NO imageUrl field, it's not there in that JSON)

```
class Publication: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    ...
    var categories = List<Categories>()

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        // map ID and Categories of this item to the Categories db
        categories <- (map["categories"], ListTransform<Categories>())
    }    
}
```

This is a part of the Publication JSON, that overwrites my Category database (as you can see, no imageUrl is given in the JSON)

```
{
    "categories": [
        {
            "id": 39,
            "name": "Etenswaren "
        },
        {
            "id": 91,
            "name": "Dranken"
        }
    ],
}
```

The issue I'm having now in my database, is that my `Categories` object's `imageUrl` is being cleared when my two calls are done (at least the categories that were found in my `Publication` class don't contain an URL anymore.)

I want the `imageUrl` column to be untouched after filling it (so that all URLs are still there, even if the Category was found in the Publication). How can I do this?

Different solutions are welcome as well.

[image]

Comment: Could you show the code that you are using to create/update these realm objects? Are you using the "update: Bool" parameter when updating?

Answer (score 1):

So you're using ObjectMapper for deserializing from JSON to your object model. For `Publication`'s property `categories`, you're relying on a custom defined transformation `ListTransform`, which I assume may look somewhat like [this gist](https://gist.github.com/zendobk/80b16eb74524a1674871#file-listtransform-swift-L9).

This `ListTransform` will create a new `List` and fill subsequently map all values from the given JSON array, if it is an array.
If you add the so created `Publication` object to the Realm, your categories would be treated as new objects unless you explicitly pass the parameter `update` as true. This however will always treat all your objects properties as new data, even empty fields, which means it overwrites filled fields in the database with `nil` values.

So you can define instead a custom `TransformType`, which looks up the objects by their primary key in the Realm.

```
public class RetrievingListTransform<T:RealmSwift.Object where T:Mappable> : TransformType {
    public typealias Object = List<T>
    public typealias JSON = [AnyObject]

    let mapper = Mapper<T>()

    public let realm: Realm

    /// Provide a function which maps the JSON to a primary key.
    public let primaryKeyTransform: ([String: AnyObject]) -> AnyObject?

    public init(realm: Realm, primaryKeyTransform: ([String: AnyObject]) -> AnyObject?) {
        self.realm = realm
        self.primaryKeyTransform = primaryKeyTransform
    }

    public func transformFromJSON(values: AnyObject?) -> Object? {
        let list = List<T>()
        guard let values = values as? [AnyObject] else {
            return list
        }
        for value in values {
            if let object = transformFromJSONArrayItemToObject(value) {
                list.append(object)
            }
        }
        return list
    }

    func transformFromJSONArrayItemToObject(json: AnyObject) -> T? {
        guard let jsonDict = json as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            return nil
        }
        guard let primaryKey = primaryKeyTransform(jsonDict) else {
            return nil
        }
        if let object = realm.objectForPrimaryKey(T.self, key: primaryKey) {
            return object
        } else {
            return mapper.map(jsonDict)
        }
    }

    public func transformToJSON(list: Object?) -> JSON? {
        guard let list = list else {
            return []
        }
        return list.map { mapper.toJSON($0) }
    }
}
```

You can use it like seen below:

```
class Publication: Object, Mappable {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    ...
    var categories = List<Categories>()

    required convenience init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        categories <- (map["categories"], RetrievingListTransform<Categories>(realm: try! Realm()) { (json: [String : AnyObject]) -> AnyObject? in
            return json["id"]
        })
    }    
}
```

The main issue when attempting to solve that, is that you'd need access to your Realm within the `mapping` function. But as the signature is given by ObjectMapper which uses final Swift classes and so offers few extension points, you can't just inject a Realm instance properly according to Dependency Injection best practices.

For that reason I'm relying here on the default Realm configuration. If you have different configurations, then it needs a little more effort, as
sharing `Realm` instances in a global accessible variable is generally not recommended as they are not thread-safe. So you could either share your `RealmConfiguration` or would need a factory method, which can return `Realm` instances for the current thread.

Comment: I lost all hope of someone responding :D currently fixed it, by giving the imageUrl from my Categories also in the Publication Object. I'll give your solution a try soon though, might be even better.